# Angular scss use @import scss file inside class

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular13

I am using Angular 13 and in my styles.scss I am trying:

```
body.theme1 {
    @import "./assets/themes/theme1.scss";
}
```

then in my app.component.html I have:

```
<div class="theme1">

    // HTML HERE

</div>
```

This is not importing the file.

Can this be done? If so how?

Answer (score 0):

You applied theme1 class to the div element in example, but in styles.scss you applied this class to the body element